# Selenium Heroku: Script is working but am still receiving H10 error

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, deployment

I have successfully deployed my selenium script to Heroku and my script is printing exactly what I want.

However, when looking at the Heroku logs, I am receiving an H10 error:
[image]

Also, I still can't see my deployed script on https://hm-new-acc-bot.herokuapp.com/

My script code :

```
from guerrillamail import GuerrillaMailSession
import requests
import time
import os
from datetime import date
from random import randrange
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Sometimes will get blank screen aka invalid SSL certificate
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
# Proxy
# chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
# Setting in case website blocks headless browser mode
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
# Give browser option to incognito
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), options=chrome_options)

session = GuerrillaMailSession()
EMAIL_ADDRESS = session.get_session_state()['email_address']
response = requests.get("https://www.passwordrandom.com/query?command=password")
PASSWORD = response.text

# PATH = r"C:\Users\yiyan\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
# Loads the H&M website
driver.get("https://www2.hm.com/en_us/register")

# Debugging
# driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot1.png")

# Accepts cookies early on to not block screen
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()

signup_page = driver.find_element_by_id("app")

# Enters in the email address
email_box = signup_page.find_element_by_id("email")
email_box.send_keys(EMAIL_ADDRESS)

time.sleep(1)

# Enters in the password
password_box = signup_page.find_element_by_name("password")
password_box.send_keys(PASSWORD)

time.sleep(1)

# Month-Day-Year constant values
today = date.today()
CURR_MONTH = today.strftime("%m")
CURR_DAY = today.strftime("%d")
CURR_YEAR = today.strftime("%Y")
# Make your birthday anywhere from 18  to 22 years ago
FAKE_YEAR = str(int(CURR_YEAR) - randrange(18, 22))

# Enters in the month for DOB
month_box = signup_page.find_element_by_name("month")
month_box.send_keys(CURR_MONTH)

time.sleep(1)

# Enters in the day for DOB
day_box = signup_page.find_element_by_name("day")
day_box.send_keys(CURR_DAY)

time.sleep(1)

# Enters in the year for DOB
year_box = signup_page.find_element_by_name("year")
year_box.send_keys(FAKE_YEAR)

time.sleep(1)

# Clicks the register button
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='submitButton']"))).click()

# driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot2.png")

print("Email Address: ", EMAIL_ADDRESS)
print("Password: ", PASSWORD)

time.sleep(5)

# driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot3.png")

driver.quit()
```

Is this because I don't have a frontend (i.e. Flask)? Currently, my script only displays the result to the console.

Lastly, what is the difference between a web and worker dyno? My script creates a unique account, by inputting a unique email and password, then prints the respective email and password. Which one should I pick?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Please post your code as text with the correct formatting. Stackoverflow posts support markdown. 2. Don't display passwords and usernames on any public forum.

Comment: For 1. do you want my script code or the text from the picture above in the correct format? For 2. the emails and passwords are generated from a burner email and password api and I couldn't crop them out of the screenshot so I just posted as is.

Comment: Please read this article, it will help you to improve your post:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Improving your post increase the chances of having a response of your question

Answer (score 0):

As the OP, I believe the issue was that I was using the incorrect dyno. After using the one-off dyno by running the command:

```
heroku run python <name of script>
```

My script ran perfectly with no issues. It seems like one-off dynos are perfect for running one-time scripts that do not have a front-end. Read more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dynos

Here is the output now:
[image]